# How to find the center of coordinates of yellow colour in a image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to find the center of yellow colour box which is in my image using opencv. It would be great if someone explain the code from scratch.

I tried to use numpy and find the coordinates. But i wasn't able to get the coordinates of all the yellow colour so that i can take avg nd find the center.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then click [edit] and improve your question. Thank you.

Comment: Also post and image to some free hosting service and put the URL in your question or a comment

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could provide more information about the image/yellow color box.

Let's assume you have an image similar to the following image:

[image]

First, we have to read the image and convert it to [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) Space. HSV value represents the color closely to what we perceive. [This article](https://cvexplained.wordpress.com/2020/04/28/color-detection-hsv/) might be helpful for you.

```
image = cv2.imread("yellow_rectangle.jpg")
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Then we have to define what is yellow for us in HSV. Using `cv2.inRange` we can get the mask for the image that falls within our defined boundary.

```
lower_yellow = (22,100,20)
upper_yellow = (35,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(image_hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)
```

[image]

Then we may use the [contour features](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) to get the center of each yellow rectangle(or any shape) we have in the image.

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, c in enumerate(cnts[0]):
    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    print(f"Yellow Box {i} : cx={cx}, cx={cy}")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with numpy?

Comment: Technically, yes. You may use `np.where(mask==255)` to find the x and y coordinates of the yellow pixels in the image, and then use this information to find the center of the rectangle.

Comment: Can you post the code where we use numpy?

Comment: `points = np.where(mask==255)`
`cx = (points[0].min()+points[0].max())/2`
`cy = (points[1].min()+points[1].max())/2`

Comment: cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero   Im getting this error